# Too many no_pubkey errors . How to fix?

Tags: apt, gnupg

After some updates a few months ago I get these outputs:

```
W: Erro GPG: http://sft.if.usp.br trusty Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: Erro GPG: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366
W: Erro GPG: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: Erro GPG: http://sft.if.usp.br trusty-updates Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: Erro GPG: http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: Erro GPG: http://sft.if.usp.br trusty-backports Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: Erro GPG: http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: Erro GPG: http://sft.if.usp.br trusty-security Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: Erro GPG: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY C71839136CF5CE97
W: Erro GPG: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 90BD7EACED8E640A
W: Erro GPG: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 9641080A705C2B92
```

I know how to fix this ordinarily, but this time I'm getting too many. Except for the first one (about intel graphics) the others seems to be related to Ubuntu itself. I have tried changing mirrors but I'm stuck with the same error.

Update : `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com`

returns this error and many similar:

```
gpg: recurso do bloco de chaves: `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/tuxpoldo-btsync.gpg': limite de recurso
```

I suppose that's "resource limit"

`

Answer (score -1):

You could try using this tool:
[Y-PPA-Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/y-ppa-manager-easily-search-add-remove.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Then there are only two clicks:

- Advanced
- Try to import all missing GPG keys

Comment: Still not working . And i don`t want to fix it manually until find the reason of the main problem .